# VBA/Excel How to save ActiveCell as object

Tags: excel, vba

i need to build login text from a list in Excel. I try myself with macro and write a small script. basically i have 2 cell one next to the other. the first one get a ssh key name, and the second get the passphrase. this 2 value depend on the os of the machine, specified in an other field. Final i have a table with the os name, and the ssh key next to the passphrase.

this is what i wrote :

```
Function FindKey(FirstCell As Range) As String
'
' FindKey Macro
' Find the ssh key in function of the OS
'
Dim Find As Boolean
Dim Cell As Range
Dim OS As String


Cell = ActiveCell.Address
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = OS
Find = False
While Not Find
    ActiveCell = FirstCell.Address
    If ActiveCell.Value = OS Then
        FindKey = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Cell.Select
        Find = True
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
            Cell.Select
            FindKey = CVErr(xlErrNull)
            Find = True
        End If
    End If

Wend
'
End Function
```

I truly have no idea of how I'm suppose to write that. Can i only store cell address in a variable ? can i use it as a object next ?

Thank you for your time and have a nice day

Comment: what issues are you facing with the code you posted? What do you need your function to return?

Comment: the issue, it dosent compile. i wilsh to return the key name get with this :
ActiveCell.Value = OS Then
        FindKey = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

and the passphrase associate in next right cell

Answer (score 1):

```
dim yourCell as Range
set yourCell = ActiveCell
```

and

```
set yourCell = FirstCell
```

You need to use the keyword set when setting an object reference

Answer (score 1):

```
Set myActiveCell = ActiveCell
Set myActiveWorksheet = ActiveSheet
'Your code here
myActiveWorksheet.Activate
myActiveCell.Activate
```